# Codeigniter pagination link go to 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I had this [Paginate with search result](http://www.andyhawthorne.co.uk/how-to-paginate-search-results-with-codeigniter/) implemented into my CI project, However I was unable to have my paginate links go to the next page, for example:

my search page when it first loaded is `http://localhost/ci_project/search`, when I clicked the paging link which will go to `http://localhost/ci_project/search/2`, the page is shown `404 Page Not Found`.

Can someone please help me to figure out what's wrong in my code? I tried a lot of suggestion on the solution but can't help, most of the issue is came from `$config['base_url'] = base_url('search');`, but none of them are help.

**Model:**

```
public function do_search_count($keywords)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM products WHERE MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ('".$keywords."')";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $q->row();
    return $row->cnt;
}

public function do_search($keywords, $per_page, $limit)
{
    $this->db->escape($keywords);

    $this->db->where('MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ("'.$keywords.'") LIMIT '.$per_page.', '.$limit, NULL, FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function search()
{
    $keywords = $this->input->post('search');

    $searchterm = $this->db_model->searchterm_handler($this->input->get_post('search', TRUE));
    $limit = ($this->uri->segment(2) > 0)?$this->uri->segment(2):0;

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('search');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db_model->do_search_count($searchterm);
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $choice = $config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page'];
    $config['num_links'] = round($choice);  

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['results'] = $this->db_model->do_search(trim($keywords), $limit, $config['per_page']);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $data['total'] = count($data['results']);
    $data['title'] = 'Search';

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('search', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('controller_name/search');
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Comment: this works, but when I go to page 2, no records is shown and it happen from page 2 to page 1

Comment: For that you need to check your query that the limit and offset is set correctly or not. Use `$this->db->last_query()` to output your query. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Nil'z my $this->db->last_query() shows `SELECT * FROM user_data LIMIT 5 ` in first page but when i click `page 2` it moves to `object not found 404`:( pls help me to solve:(

Comment: @Nil'z I have followed this  [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/).Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/ci_project/search/2` in codeigniter is probably trying to execute a method called `2` with the usual configuration, if your method is `search` be sure to call the url at `http://localhost/ci_project/search_controller/search/2`.

If you want to change the configuration for some reason, you can start diggin [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: I has remap `$route['search/(:num)'] = 'search_controller/search/$1';` in routes.php. now my paginate links are works, but when I go to the next page `http://localhost/irenov/search/2`, no remain records is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/controller_name/method_name');
```

No need change routes config, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** 
If Your are on Index Page Call to Index Method Like This..

```
'base_url' => base_url('page/index'),
```